# Windows 10 iso file got Deleted on it's own after a Reboot!

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Windows 10 Pro in my virtual box, ran it for sometime and then rebooted my host (Ubuntu) machine. After that i opened virtual box again. I got a warning saying:

> One or more disk image files are not currently accessible. As a result, you will not be able to operate virtual machines that use these files until they become accessible later...

I am pretty sure i didn't delete the disk image myself. It also happened before when i installed windows XP in virtual box and then after rebooting the host machine, the iso file got deleted on it's own.

Interestingly, i can still run windows 10 in virtual box despite the warning! I want to know what caused this issue and is there a way i can fix it?

Comment: Can you check the physical location of the ISO file in the host machine? Once you install Windows in the VM you don't need the ISO file, just as you would take the DVD out from the drive in a physical machine. You have to detach the ISO from Virtual Box's settings.

Answer (score 3):

The message you are seeing is a status message of images that you have registered to Virtual Box.  It retains this information until you release it.  The disks are not necessarily mounted.

You can identify the disk that is flagged by clicking on the <kbd>Check</kbd> button of the warning message.  Note, this is a warning information box, not an error.

The check button will bring up the **Virtual Media Manager**.  From there click on the `Optical Disk` tab. then scroll down to the source of the warning, identified by a triangle with an exclamation mark.  Pointing to it will show you the pathname where it was located last.

You can safely click on the item in the menu bar to `Remove` it.  The prompt will notify you that removing the entry will not delete the file.

There is also a delete media option.  But this only functions on media that doesn't have the warning flag.

The next time you start Virtual Box you won't be greeted with the error message.

Since you mentioned that you didn't delete the iso file, you can locate it in your system by typing this command:

```
$ locate [en_windows_10_pro_x64_dvd_6851151.iso]
```

Replace the name in the brackets with the name of the file you want to find.